# The limit of the probability that a random variable is greater than a constant is zero?

Tags: probability-theory

I was just wondering if $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}P(X>a)=0$ for any random variable $X.$

It seems quite obvious but can we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A_n = \{ \omega : X(\omega) > n\}$, then
$$\lim_{a \rightarrow\infty} P(X > a) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n)$$
Since $A_n \supseteq A_{n+1}$ for every $n$, the sequence $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a decreasing sequence of nested sets. Furthermore, 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \{\omega : X(\omega) > n \text{ for every }n\} = \{\omega : X(\omega) = +\infty\}$$
and so
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) = P(X = +\infty)$$
which has probability zero if $X$ is a real-valued random variable, but may have nonzero probability if $X$ is extended-real-valued.

Comment: Would you please take a look at my solution below? I am not sure if it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean. I can define $X(\omega) \equiv \infty$ for all $\omega$. If you take the specific case of an integrable random variable (i.e., $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$), then this follows directly from Markov's inequality:
\begin{gather*}
P(|X| \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}|X|}{a} \xrightarrow{a \rightarrow \infty}{0}.
\end{gather*}

Comment: There are many real-valued random variables whose expectations do not exist.

Comment: You are right, Bungo's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was thinking but not sure if it's correct.
We want to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}_{X>n}=0\text{ for integers }n.$$

By Dominated Convergence Theorem,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}_{X>n}&=&\mathbb{E}\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf{1}_{X>n}\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray*}
where the second equality is justified by the following.

Since $X$ takes finite values, for any fixed $\omega\in\Omega,$ $\mathbf{1}_{X(\omega)>n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty.$

Thus $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{1}_{X>n}=0)=1$

Comment: This is also correct. DCT applies since the integrand is bounded by an integrable function (the constant function 1), and $1_{X>n}(\omega)$ converges pointwise to $0$ since, for any $\omega$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $X(\omega) \leq n$.

Comment: I am often very suspicious when applying DCT. Because indicator functions only take values 0 or 1, thus always bounded, does that mean they always converge?

Comment: Boundedness and convergence are separate concepts. If $X_n$ are iid $N(0,1)$ and $A_n$ denotes the event that $X_n \geq 0$, then $A_n$ and $A_n^c$ occur infinitely almost surely by Borel-Cantelli. Therefore, for almost every $\omega$, $1_{A_n} = 1$ and $ = 0 $ infinitely often, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1_{A_n}$ does not exist.

Comment: Oops. Sorry I confused the concept. How about this? Suppose the indicator functions converge, we can always move the limit sign inside the expectation.

Comment: To say $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int f_n d\mu = \int f d\mu$, it is sufficient to have $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise and existence of $g \in L^1(\mu)$ such that $g \geq |f_n|$ for all $n$. In your specific case of $f_n = 1_{A_n}$ and $\mu$ a probability measure, we can take $g = 1$ and then, yes, it suffices to check pointwise convergence. One often sees the mistaken belief that it is sufficient to bound the integrand: $\left|\int f_n d\mu\right| \leq g$, which is wrong (take $1_{[n,n+1]}$ on $\mathbb{R}$).